# How can I map one record to another using a lookup field in salesforce?

Tags: trigger, opportunity, lookup, list

I hope you are well, I would like to ask for your help with something that you have in mind and I can not do it haha

If I have two different object record lists and the first record list has a lookup field towards the second object and it is worth mentioning that the lists are the same size.

How can I assign a record from list 2 to each record from list 1?

These are my two lists:

```
rv = [Select Id, Name, Meta__c, CancellationDateRV__c, AccumulationGroupRV__c 
              From Resumen_de_Ventas__c
              Where Oportunidad__c in: opps];

mts = [Select Id, Name, AccumulationGroup__c, Fecha_de_inicio__c, Fecha_fin__c, Usuario__c
                   from Metas__c 
                   where Fecha_de_inicio__c <=: CancellationDate and Fecha_fin__c >=: CancellationDate and AccumulationGroup__c =:accumulationGroup];
```

The situation or panorama of the operation is that when an opportunity is canceled, the records of "Summary_de_ventas__c", in the field "Meta__c" change to the goal that corresponds to the cancellation date, this cancellation date is formulated in the sale summary from the opportunity.

How can I achieve this?
I really appreciate your support.

Comment: the `Resumen_de_Ventas__c.Meta__c` is lookup to the `Metas__c` object?

Comment: @Damecek it is master-detail, but it is configured so that it can be modified, and it is from Metas__c

Answer (score 0):

As you stated that the `Resumen_de_Ventas__c.Meta__c` is lookup to the `Metas__c` object, you could avoid all of this with this simple query.

```
Select Id, Name, Meta__c, CancellationDateRV__c, AccumulationGroupRV__c,
    Meta__r.Id, Meta__r.Name, Meta__r.AccumulationGroup__c, Meta__r.Fecha_de_inicio__c, Meta__r.Fecha_fin__c, Meta__r.Usuario__c
              From Resumen_de_Ventas__c
              Where Oportunidad__c in: opps AND
    Meta__r.Fecha_de_inicio__c <=: CancellationDate and Meta__r.Fecha_fin__c >=: CancellationDate and Meta__r.AccumulationGroup__c =:accumulationGroup
```

This would give you the intersection of the two lists above.

Or you could go the other way around and have all Metas__c and some of them will have the related Resume_de_Ventas__c like so.

```
Select Id, Name, AccumulationGroup__c, Fecha_de_inicio__c, Fecha_fin__c, Usuario__c, (Select Id, Name, Meta__c, CancellationDateRV__c, AccumulationGroupRV__c 
              From **Resumen_de_Ventas__r**
              Where Oportunidad__c in: opps)
                   from Metas__c 
                   where Fecha_de_inicio__c <=: CancellationDate and Fecha_fin__c >=: CancellationDate and AccumulationGroup__c =:accumulationGroup
```

Pls be aware that i am only guessing the relation name above `**Resumen_de_Ventas__r**` so this probably will need some adjustments.

Comment: Thank you so much!
With the second option I obtain the Metas__c that would correspond to the Resumen_de_vetnas__c ... How can I assign those Metas__c to each Resumen_de_ventas__c that were found in the opportunity?

In the opportunity there are always 4 Resumenes_de_ventas__c and there should always be 4 Metas__c that correspond to the cancellation date